# How to clear the way for a space elevator?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, debris, space-elevator

In the answer to [this question about space elevators](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/where-could-we-build-a-space-elevator-today-2014), the poster mentioned that the elevator cable would pass through a debris cloud as it moved through lower orbits.  I presume most of that material is "space junk", but some of it must be functioning satellites.  If we were to discover technology that enabled us to build a space elevator tomorrow, how would we clear a place for it to go?

Comment: Moving all satellites to semi-synchronous orbits would work - orbits that pass over a specific point of Earth every *n* periods, *n* being an integer and not excessively large (say, under 10,000). That way given satellite also *misses* a certain set of points always.

Comment: I'd imagine the elevator cable would have active thrusters to move a few kilometers in one direction or the other. Even after clearing orbit, there's still natural debris (meteoroid etc.) to avoid.